# Android Location API does not show mock locations onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am struggling with android location api in getting constant updates of my device's current location. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class ViewMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final Long LOCATION_MIN_TIME = 1000L;
    public static final float LOCATION_MIN_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private static GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private  Criteria criteria;
    private String provider;


    public ViewMapActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("ViewMap"," Map created");
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
        mapOptions.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mapOptions.zoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mapOptions.zoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment))
                .getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,  false);
        //Log.d("ViewMap", provider.toString());

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            Log.d("ViewMap", "Location found onCreate."+location.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("ViewMap", "Paused");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("ViewMap", "Resume");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("ViewMap", "location changed");
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(15)); //TODO: move this to static config
        String loc = "Lat:"+latLng.latitude+" long:"+latLng.longitude;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("ViewMap", latLng.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("ViewMap", "Status Changed: "+s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Log.d("ViewMap", "GPS Provider");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
        } else {
            Log.d("ViewMap", "Network Provider");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.i("ViewMap", "GPS can work now");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.i("ViewMap", "GPS is disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
       // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.e("ViewMap", "Google play connection failed. GPS might not work");
    }
}
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           package="com.sample.activity"
           android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"/>

    <permission
            android:name="com.sample.activity.permissions.MAP_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />


    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="SplashScreenStartActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ViewMapActivity"/>



        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     </application> </manifest>
```

As a follow up question, how do I test this activity with passing mock locations. I am using mock location example from http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html . The marker does show mock location but onLocation always shows current location

Comment: The marker does show mock location but onLocation always shows current location  --so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is the current location shows the real current location and not by the location provided by the test app provided by http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html. I can see the current marker moving across different mock locations but onLocationChanged always shows my real location and not the mock locations.

Answer (score 2):

Mock location only works for GPS, it will not fake any other provider.  Specifically it will not fake the NETWORK location provider.  Don't use criteria to pick the best provider, specify the GPS provider.

Generally I don't think Criteria are useful.  You wrote your app, you know whether you need the accuracy of GPS or want to save battery with network.  Specify what you want rather than have the OS pick one for you.

Comment: You mean if get GPS_PROVIDER i will be able to listen to mock locations. I guess I had tried that earlier but didn't work. Let me try that again and I will let you know.

Comment: There's nothing true in this answer.  You can use any provider name for a mock location provider.  Using Criteria is a great idea because it separates what you *want* from what is *available*.  (If you directly specify GPS and it's turned off, you're SOL)

Comment: @RobertLiberatore criteria are overly complicated and provide 0 extra value. You know what you need, if you need GPS, just request it. If not, don't. I've never written an app where I'd want to use non GPS of it wasn't on, I'd rather fail and ask for it to be turned on. I need that accuracy, or I don't and I use network. It's possible that today mock providers can be used for any provider, I haven't used location on a few years. It was definitely NOT true when this answer was written.

Comment: I just successfully ran a made-up mock provider on API 18. /shrug

Your attitude towards location providers is why Android is moving away from allowing developers to choose a provider directly (see "Fused Location Provider").  There are many more factors than accuracy that should be weighted, and relying on a single provider type is frankly just bad advice.

Comment: No, using criteria and not understanding the problem you're trying to solve and using the correct provider for it is lazy programming and unnecessarily intrusive into you user's privacy.  If you don't absolutely need GPS, you should be requesting network.  Always use the least accurate that will give you acceptable results.Doing anything else is sleazy.  And the FusedProvider thing is lock in trying to force people to use Google Play Services and kill off several forks like Fire that were forming.  That's the main reason they made it (and why it isn't in platform).

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question with the set of imports for your activity, will edit/remove my answer if its incorrect.
Why you always see the current location may be because of the [googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29) in `onCreate()`

Frankly, the code in question seems a copy-paste from multiple sources without understanding much or the details have been overlooked, not so mildly.

Code contains a mix of two methods of obtaining user's location.
***1.*** Using [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html), [Retrieving the Current Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
This implements interfaces from [GooglePlayServicesClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient.html)
The package is `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` so its this [LocationListener.](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html)
On the link of [Testing Using Mock Locations](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html), this one has been used.

***2.*** Using [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)
with which you would use the method `requestLocationUpdates()`. Here the package is `android.location` so its this [LocationListener.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

***What that means for your code:***
***1.1*** You have implemented the Listeners for the first method, but you never set, call or use [locationClient.connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#connect%28%29) so the following part of the code is never called.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.i("ViewMap", "GPS can work now");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.i("ViewMap", "GPS is disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
       // TODO may be add some logs
        Log.e("ViewMap", "Google play connection failed. GPS might not work");
    }
```

You should go for this method as you are using Google Play Services anyway.

***2.1***   `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);`
This is what gets you the location if you have imported the correct LocationListener. You can check in imports, if it is not the `android.location` package, i don't think the code ever reaches there.

Comment: Added some import statements. Yes you are right the code is simply copy-paste of code from different sources. I am new to these concepts.